# Problem with Python SciPy module

Tags: python

I am trying to run a Python program, and when I run `python ldbb.py`, I get the following error:

```
root@dell-OptiPlex-3050:~/refractiveindex.info-scripts-master/ldbb# python ldbb.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ldbb.py", line 29, in <module>
    from scipy import constants
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Did you install scipy before you use it in the script?

Comment: after installing the scipy now when i am trying to run the program it is showing that 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot

Now what should i do please suggest me.

Comment: /usr/lib/python*/dist-packages/ **matplotlib/pyplot.py** : `sudo apt install python-matplotlib python3-matplotlib` .... or the one that fits your python version.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to explain how you installed Python and SciPy? What's the output of `command -v python`, `python --version`, `python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path))'` and `apt-cache policy python-scipy`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't install scipy..

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

then

```
pip install scipy
```

should solve your problem.